# Prove a function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(x^p+x^{-p})f\in L^2(0,\infty)$, where $p>\frac{1}{2}$. How can we show $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$ ?

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $f=(x^p+x^{-p})^{-1}(x^p+x^{-p})f$ and Hölder's inequality (self dual case, $1=1/2+1/2$) by noting that $(x^p+x^{-p})^{-1}\in L^2$, considering that $|(x^p+x^{-p})^{-1}|^2\leqslant (x^{2p}+2)^{-1}$ (the latter lies in $L^1$ as $2p>1$).

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @Ylath: I added some more details, is it enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have already know how to proof by your first hint.